# Why can we not use L'Hopitals' rule to prove $\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{x^2 \sin \frac{1}{x}}{\sin x}=0$?

Tags: calculus, limits

This is a problem in Schaum's outline -- Advanced Calculus, page 89, problem 4.84.

Why we cannot use L'Hopitals' rule to prove $$\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{x^2 \sin \dfrac{1}{x}}{\sin x}=0\;?$$

I thought the numerator $x^2 \sin \dfrac{1}{x}$ goes to $0$ as $x$ goes to $0$,
since $x^2$ goes to 0 and $\sin \dfrac{1}{x}$is bounded. And the denominator goes to 0 too. But why we can not use L'Hopitals' rule here?

Comment: Who said you can't?

Comment: Any reference for this question ?

Comment: because the derivative of the numerator has no limit at $0$.

Comment: Yeah what @AbdallahHammam said. The limit gets smaller and bigger. It doesn't approach a certain value.

Comment: @AbdallahHammam's got the right answer. In order to conclude that $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ you need the second limit to exist or be $\pm \infty$. But neither is the case for $f'(x)$ in this case.

Comment: @AbdallahHammam As $x$ goes to 0, $x^2$ goes to $0$ and $\sin \dfrac{1}{x}$ is bounded, why the limit does not exist?

Comment: @NanLi The *derivative* of $x^2\sin(1/x)$ doesn't have a limit at $0$.

Comment: i said the limit of the derivative $2xsin(\frac{1}{x})-cos(\frac{1}{x})$

Comment: @AbdallahHammam I think you did it wrong, it should be $2x\sin \dfrac{1}{x}+x^2 \cos \dfrac{1}{x}$

Comment: @NanLi No, Abdallah is correct. You forgot to use the chain rule. The derivative of $\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ is $-\frac{1}{x^2}\cos(\frac{1}{x})$.

Comment: @kccu, ah.. yeah...

Comment: The question "why can we not use L'Hopital'rule?" is problematic and unclear to me. To make it a better question, 

 - If you think you can, you could show us. 
 - If you think L'Hopital'rule is not applicable, then you could show us
   why *you* think it is not applicable.
 - If the problem says that you should use L'Hopital's rule, but you don't know how, then you could show us where you got stuck and ask instead "how can I apply L'Hopital rule?".

Comment: The funny thing about this problem is that you *can* use L'Hopital's Rule, albeit indirectly. Use the fact that $$\biggl| \dfrac{x^2 \sin \dfrac{1}{x}}{\sin x} \biggr| = \biggl| \dfrac{x^2}{\sin x} \biggr| \cdot \bigr|  \sin \dfrac{1}{x} \bigr| \le\biggl| \dfrac{x^2}{\sin x} \biggr| $$ and therefore, to prove that your limit approaches zero, it suffices by the sandwich theorem to prove that $\dfrac{x^2}{\sin x}$ approaches zero. Which you can do using L'Hopital's Rule, if you so desire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

L'Hopitals says that if $\lim\limits_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} $ is of the form
$\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ or $\frac{0}{0}$ and if 
 $$\lim\limits_{x\to a}\frac{f^{\prime}(x)}{g^{\prime}(x)} $$ exists then the first limit exits and the two limits are equal.

In this case we have the form $\frac{0}{0}$. OK. But now we find that

$$\frac{f^{\prime}(x)}{g^{\prime}(x)} =\frac{2x\sin\frac{1}{x}-\cos \frac{1}{x}}{\cos x}$$ and this limit does not exist, thus nothing can be concluded.

Answer (score 0):

Take the derivative of the numerator:
$$
2x\sin\frac{1}{x}+x^2\left[\cos\frac{1}{x}\right]\cdot\left(-\frac{1}{x^2}\right).
$$
This would not get you anywhere if you want to apply L'Hopital *directly*, **because** the assumptions are not satisfied.

For the sake of calculation, note that
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{x^2 \sin \dfrac{1}{x}}{\sin x}=
\lim_{x \to 0} \left(x\cdot\frac{x}{\sin x}\cdot\sin\frac{1}{x}\right).
$$

Also, you could try "simpler problems" first:

- Do you know what is the limit $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{\sin x}?$$
- Can you show that $$\lim_{x \to 0} \left(x \cdot\sin\frac{1}{x}\right)=0?$$

---

For the part of calculating $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{\sin x}$ above, you *can* use L'Hopital rule.